# bitcoin-cli: how to create a wallet and utxo address

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I am a relative newbie in bitcoin and blockchain and hope you can help me with some of the questions.
So I launched a "regtest" network and generated 101 blocks using

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 101
```

Now, if I launch 'bitcoin-cli -regtest getaddressesbyaccount ""', I get the public address of my default account:

```
[
  "mwpKJNJ4UZL7yFyj53RSVcwauGAK84UvV2"
]
```

And of course, I should not have any other accounts as for now.
When I launch 'bitcoin-cli -regtest listunspent':

```
[
  {
    "txid": "694030f8638318c8c54054515ec716159edc494b14234885deb48f294b75a2fe",
    "vout": 0,
    "address": "n1queZpweTHjrMLvwSmcfrrJSQjsrYG3nG",
    "scriptPubKey": "21038cadb266ed1ae6c474f5c1b74fc5f6790eacde843a673a16cfc924a100f2a679ac",
    "amount": 50.00000000,
    "confirmations": 101,
    "spendable": true,
    "solvable": true,
    "safe": true
  }
]
```

First question: 
I understand that the only transaction listed by "listunspent" is UTXO, 
meaning this is a transaction what I received to my address "n1queZpweTHjrMLvwSmcfrrJSQjsrYG3nG" with 50 BTC as amount.
Where this address comes from? By what bitcoin-cli command I can see/find it in my wallet?

Second question:
How can I create a new wallet with some balances and switch between them ( using bitcoin-cli )?
Basically, I would like to be able to test my app using bitcoin-cli - I need to be able to create wallets, switch between them and send btc between the addresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coinbase coins can't be transferred until 100 blocks after they were created.

(**Why did you generate "101" blocks specifically?**)

So, the amount in your wallet you see is from the first block you mined. You can verify that by `bitcoin-cli -regtest getblock "<hash of first block>"` which you had got in return to the `generate 101` command you ran earlier (an array of 101 block hashes).

Try the following

- generate one more block `bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 1`
- now `listunspent` and you should see 2 utxos instead of 1.

Depending on what you want to test, maybe simply creating a new address and sending money to it is enough for you?

[Edit]

1. Shut down core properly.
2. Rename your wallet.dat file
3. When you restart, a new wallet(wallet.dat) will be created. You can use them by supplying `-wallet` arg to `bitcoin-qt`

For example, if you are on linux:

Create 4 wallets by starting bitcoin core, stopping bitcoin core and then renaming the *wallet.dat* in your **~/.bitcoin** folder (then repeating the process). For example, run this process 4 times to generate :

- mywallet.dat
- wifeswallet.dat
- kidswallet.dat
- businesswallet.dat

Then, in linux, in your **.bashrc** :

```
alias mywallet="bitcoin-qt -wallet=~/.bitcoin/mywallet.dat"
alias wifeswallet="bitcoin-qt -wallet=~/.bitcoin/wifeswallet.dat"
alias kidswallet="bitcoin-qt -wallet=~/.bitcoin/kidswallet.dat"
alias businesswallet="bitcoin-qt -wallet=~/.bitcoin/businesswallet.dat"
```

Comment: Regarding 101: to be honest I just took it from some example.
But I still don't get where does the address "n1queZpweTHjrMLvwSmcfrrJSQjsrYG3nG" comes from and how can I find it ( or ensure that it belongs to my wallet ) ?

Can I create a new wallet and switch between wallets ( and not between the accounts in one wallet )?

Comment: @user3489820 That address is the address of your wallet that got paid/mined to in the first block. You can find it in the first block.

For multiple wallets, you can simply use `bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=<file>`. Aditionally editing the answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply how to create additional wallets.
However, I still don't understand where this address comes from.

I understand that this address should be mine and the first block created has a coinbase transaction to this address, so that's how I got it.

I don't understand how to check if this address is mine or not.
How to see if it's in my addresses or not.
I try to make 'bitcoin-cli -regtest getaddressesbyaccount ""', but this address is not there. Will I receive coins if I make a new transaction to this address?